# Get errors with javamail

Tags: java

i'm trying an example of javamail and i get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTH] Application-specific password required: http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833
            at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
            at javax.mail.Session.getFolder(Session.java:612)
            at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:19)
    Java Result: 1
```

The code used is from Java2s.com Get Attachment File Name.
And i use mail.jar from 1.4.4 version.

I don't understand the end of the code
here:

```
class MailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

  public MailAuthenticator() {
  }

  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you read http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&guide=1056283&page=guide.cs&answer=185833&rd=3 ?

Comment: no but now i read this and thank you

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i used the link from Joe Tuskan.
Now when i run my code it's working but i want to understand why it shows only the byte long size and the line number.

If i read my code example here:
it seems that the disposition is null, what is that? and why?

And thank you.

   

     ...
              String disposition = messages[i].getDisposition();
              if (disposition == null){
                ; // do nothing
              }else if (disposition.equals(Part.INLINE)) {
                System.out.println("This part should be displayed inline");
        ...

Comment: Hi, glad to help. I would open a new question with that to get another answer. I'm not sure tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account in question is set-up for two-step authentication in Google.  (See [here](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&answer=180744&rd=3)).  You cannot authenticate with a simple username and password combination.

You will need to follow the instructions (the [link](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833) is right within the error message itself, which is nice) to set-up an application-specific password (e.g., revert to normal one-step authentication for Google Mail) for that specific account.

Comment: 3018 bytes long.
-1 lines.
1642 bytes long.
-1 lines.
925 bytes long.
-1 lines.
4557 bytes long

Comment: Thank you, i used the link from Joe Tuskan.
Now when i run my code it's working but i want to understand why it shows only the byte long size and the line number.

If i read my code example here:
it seems that the disposition is null, what is that? and why?

And thank you.

   

     ...
              String disposition = messages[i].getDisposition();
              if (disposition == null){
                ; // do nothing
              }else if (disposition.equals(Part.INLINE)) {
                System.out.println("This part should be displayed inline");
        ...

Comment: I agree with @JoeTuskan and would pose that as a separate question.